# Android Studio - Build Android Example projects (No Build File)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I wanted to check out some examples, so I went to the Android training page: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html). Downloaded an example, tried to open it in Android Studio but it is not recognized as a Project.

What is the procedure to use

[image]

**That's what I get in Android Studio:**

[image]

Any hints? Are those examples not supposed to have some gradle files?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, those would be complete projects. In practice, not all are. In this case, you just get a hunk of Java code and resources, with no manifest and no Gradle build files.

Hence, I would use those files as inspiration for your own code in your own project.

Comment: That's a Pitty, I am not getting this examples from a random developers page but Android. I've kinda expected, that they would provide some source files and a documentation on how to best use them.

Comment: @user1767754: It varies. Those that are hosted on GitHub are more likely to be complete projects and have some amount of documentation.